# Adding voice to Mary TTS Java from folder

Tags: java, marytts

I have a few voices that I downloaded to a folder with Mary TTS. I have taken all the jar files of mary tts including voices. My problem is that I require the voices folder, how do I integrate that folder with java.

Comment: Have you found an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Put extra voices under the marytts-XXX/lib directory. Then marytts server indexes them automatically.